# Installing g++ 5 on Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, g++, c++14, rhel

I'm trying to install g++ 5.x on an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux; in Amazon's central repository the latest version is 4.8.3. What configuration to can I make to allow `yum` to find a newer gcc-c++ package?

[image: console log]

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I also need to install g++ 4.9 or higher

Comment: @Chris Herve published a working answer below (and that should be accepted)

Answer (score 36):

Late to the party, but for those like me:

`sudo yum install gcc72 gcc72-c++`

Comment: Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package gcc72 available.
No package gcc72-c++ available.

Answer (score 22):

For Amazon Linux 2, you have to install the following

`sudo yum install -y gcc-c++`

It's a requirement to install some Ruby gems that need native extensions

Answer (score 10):

Installing gcc5:

```
# Install required libraries
sudo yum install libmpc-devel mpfr-devel gmp-devel

# Gather source code
export GCC_VERSION=5.5.0
cd /tmp
curl -o "gcc-${GCC_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
  https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-${GCC_VERSION}/gcc-    ${GCC_VERSION}.tar.gz
tar xvzf "gcc-${GCC_VERSION}.tar.gz"
cd gcc-${GCC_VERSION}

# Configure and compile
./configure --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++
make -j 8

# Install
sudo make install
```

Ensure `/usr/local/bin/` is in your `PATH`

You may advantageously install version 7.3.0 released on 25th January 18 [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/)

Comment: `make -j 1` is better should you be using a `t2.micro`. 8 at a time kills it

Comment: Hey when I execute `make -j 8` command, It executed so may process but after some time I got Can not allocate memory error message and it also shows message that Waiting for unfinished jobs... . Can you please help me in this?

Comment: When I go in `tmp` and execute the step as you say. Now I didn't get that what is the role  of `/usr/local/bin/` path. When is path comes in picture?

Comment: @SachinShah It is possible that the process differs now that AWS provide AmazonLinux 2 images. I haven't tried. Regarding the memory issue. Simply remove the `-j 8` option.

Comment: @herve I have fixed that issue by expanding the instance size from t2.micro to t2.small.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `yum whatprovides g++` and it will output a list of different packages versions that provide the the `g++` file.

example output:

```
...
gcc-c++-7.3.1-12.amzn2.x86_64 : C++ support for GCC
Repo        : amzn2-core
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/g++



gcc-c++-7.3.1-13.amzn2.x86_64 : C++ support for GCC
Repo        : amzn2-core
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/g++
```

Answer (score -1):

On Amazon Linux 2 you can run `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"` which will install many compilers and dependencies including g++

Answer (score -4):

Probably like "amazon linux ami release 2016.03", when you have gcc-4.8.3 .
This OS is very close to CentOS 7.2 / RHEL 7.

Please try : # `yum install centos-release-scl`

If OK, you can do : # `yum install devtoolset-4-gcc-c++` ... and get g++, gcc version 5.2.1 .

Enabling "5.2.1" : $ `scl enable devtoolset-4 bash` . Be aware that the setting is valid for the current terminal session only.

If any issues, I can supply a link to the four packages required for g++, gcc.

Comment: even in Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09

Comment: No package centos-release-scl available on amazon linux

Comment: `yum install scl-utils-20120229-1.el6.x86_64`